# Renaming the excel file

Tags: c#, ssis

Is there any way to rename the excel file already present on weekly basis.
While renaming the the name should be appended with the start and end date.
Actually i have used File.Move to serve this purpose.
but it is throwing me file not found exception .It worked fine for the first time but now it is showing file not found exception.
Can any body tell me how to resolve this issue or any other method to rename an excel file.
I have used SSIS package script task .

The error I am getting is as follows.

> Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
>   ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\windows\system32\old.xlsx'.
>   File name: 'C:\windows\system32\old.xlsx'

Comment: If you get an exception, then there's something wrong with your code. If you'd post your code here, we may could help you. You could start cmd with the rename command as argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created an paramter (Filname) but you are not using it.

I would change your method like that:

```
public void Main()
{
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        ExcelRefresh((string)Dts.Variables["User::Destpath"].Value, "old.xlsx", "new.xlsx");
}

private void ExcelRefresh(string sourceDirectory, string oldFileName, string newFileName) //optionally add destDirectory if you really want to move the file
{
    File.Move(sourceDirectory +"\\" + oldFileName, sourceDirectory +"\\"+ newFileName);
}
```

And don't forget to wrap your code into Try...Catch (ExceptionHandling)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // Move a file found on the C:\ volume.
    // If the file is not found (SAM.txt doesn't exist),
    // then you will get an exception.
    //
    try
    {
        File.Move(@"C:\SAM.txt", @"C:\SAMUEL.txt"); // Try to move

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {

    }
    }
}
```

In this code, if the "SAMUEL.txt" file on the C volume already exists, you will get another exception. To solve this problem, you can check the target path with the File.Exists method before attempting the File.Move.